# Replace all negative values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve this problem on codewars and I'm completely stumped:

```
y = [-1, -1, 2, 8, -1, 4]
z = [1,3,5]
#to create [1,3,2,8,5,4]
```

How would I do this?

I tried to do:

```
for e in range(len(y)):
    try:
        if y[e] < 0:
            y[e] = z[e]
    except:
        pass
```

But this would only work if the negatives correspond to what is in z.

Comment: So what's your expected result if the length of negative numbers is not equal with length of `z`.

Comment: It will always be equal.

Comment: Ex: y = [-1,2,2,1,-1] z = [5,5]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are sure that number of negative numbers is always equal with `z` you can convert `z` to an iterable and use a list comprehension for creating your new list:

```
In [9]: z = iter(z)

In [10]: [next(z) if i < 0 else i for i in y]
Out[10]: [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```

Note that if the length of `z` is shorter than number of negative numbers it will raise an `StopIteration` error.

Comment: Use `next` is very gracefulness and elegance :-)

Answer (score 3):

One-liner. Emulate queue behavior using `pop()`. (*Note this consumes* `z`)

```
>>> print([num if num > 0 else z.pop(0) for num in y])
[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it destroys z.  So you might need to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the same index for both lists, which doesn't appear to be the correct behaviour from your example. For example, the -1 in `y` is at index 4, but is replaced by the 5 in `z` at index 2.

```
zindex = 0
for yindex in range(len(y)):
    if y[yindex] < 0:
        y[yindex] = z[zindex]
        zindex += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
for e in range(len(y)):
    if y[e] < 0: y[e] = z[e]
```

The problem with your code is let's say the 5th element is negative. You are attempting to set the 5th element of `y` to the 5th element of `z`. Instead, you should use a counter variable to track which element to substitute.

```
element_z_index = 0
for e in range(len(y)):
    if y[e] < 0:
        y[e] = z[element_z_index]
        element_z_index += 1
```